# creating kendall correlation matrix

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

i have data that looks like this :
[image]

in total 38 columns .
data code sample :

```
    df <- structure(
        list(
          Christensenellaceae = c(
            0.010484508,
            0.008641566,
            0.010017172,
            0.010741488,
            0.1,
            0.2,
            0.3,
            0.4,
            0.7,
            0.8,
            0.9,
            0.1,
            0.3,
            0.45,
            0.5,
            0.55
),
          Date=c(27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28),
          Treatment = c(
            "Treatment 1",
            "Treatment 1",
            "Treatment 1",
            "Treatment 1",
            "Treatment 2",
            "Treatment 2",
            "Treatment 2",
            "Treatment 2",
             "Treatment 1",
             "Treatment 1",
              "Treatment 1",
             "Treatment 1",
            "Treatment 2",
             "Treatment 2",
             "Treatment 2",
             "Treatment 2"
   )
        ),class = "data.frame",
        row.names = c(NA,-9L)
      )
```

whay i wish to do is to create kendall correlation matrix (the data doesnt have linear behavor) between the treatment types(10 in total but 2 in example)for every column  (except treatment and date) so in total 36 correlation matrix with size 10*10 (here will be 2*2) .

this is my code:

```
res2 <- cor(as.matrix(data),method ="kendall")
```

but i get the error:

```
Error in cor(data, method = "kendall") : 'x' must be numeric
```

is there any way to solve this ? thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using a `tidyverse` approach by first making some data wrangling and then using `correlate` to calculate the correlation in pairs for every combination of variables.

```
library(corrr)
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  # Transform data into wide format
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Date, 
              names_from = Treatment,
              values_from = -starts_with(c("Treatment", "Date"))) |>
  # Unnest lists inside each column
  unnest(cols = starts_with("Treatment")) |>
  # Remove Date from the columns
  select(-Date) |>
  # Correlate all columns using kendall
  correlate(method = "kendall")

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  term        `Treatment 1` `Treatment 2`
#  <chr>               <dbl>         <dbl>
#1 Treatment 1        NA             0.546
#2 Treatment 2         0.546        NA
```

Comment: if instead ony  values_from = Christensenellaceae (1 column) i have multiple columns 36 what should i do ?@Jonathan V. Solórzano, and if i have 10 trearment types should i write them all in unnest(cols = c(`Treatment 1`, `Treatment 2`))

Comment: should i write in  values_from = Christensenellaceae for multuple columns:  values_from = colnames(data)

Comment: I edited the answer to make it easier to select multiple columns

Comment: Error in stats::cor(x = x, y = y, use = use, method = method) : 
  'x' must be numeric
In addition: There were 36 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Comment: is it beacuse  the treatment column is character?

Comment: Make sure that all the columns are numeric, before applying `correlate`. You can convert them to numeric using `mutate_at(vars(col), as.numeric)` or remove undesired columns in the `select` step.

Comment: i checked it is becuse of the reatmnet column i did that befor runing your code    f2=f %>% mutate_at(vars(colnames(f)), as.numeric) :Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `treatment`.
i `treatment = .Primitive("as.double")(treatment)`.
i NAs introduced by coercion  but it made the treatment column be al NA  will it fix it i ichange the Treatment 1.... Treatment 10 ) to numbers  form 1 to 10, how did it work for you? beacuse in the data code sample the treatment column is also not numeric

Comment: I forgot to tell you that your `dput` data has an error. R will show a warning when creating the `df` object. Try defining `df` simply as `data.frame(Christensenellaceae  = ..., Date = ..., Treatment = ...`

Comment: didnt understand what you mean shoud i make any changes when i read the data from csv file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240184/discussion-between-jonathan-v-solorzano-and-eliza-r).